How to reuse lexing rules in specific modes?
I want to parse the 'formatted string', e.g.
f"1 + 1 = {1+1}"

When recognizing f", I should enter a new mode, say, formatted_string_mode, and shall exit this mode when I encounter another ". Therefore:
'f"' -> pushMode(formatted_string_mode);

mode formatted_string_mode;
'"' -> popMode;

Meanwhile, I also need to deal with the format expr inside {}. This confuses me, that how could I reuse rules of another mode(or the defualt mode) within a specific mode?
For example, I could design another mode, called formatted_expr_mode, and enter it when I encounter { within formatted_string_mode:
// ... suppose I have some existing rules to parse an expr.
'f"' -> pushMode(formatted_string_mode);

mode formatted_string_mode;
'"' -> popMode;
'{' -> pushMode(formatted_expr_mode);
STRING_SEGMENT: ~["{] ;

mode formatted_expr_mode;
'}' -> popMode;
// how could I reuse existing rules of the default mode here?


You can use a rule in one mode that is defined in another mode. But, it is best to just use fragment for rules you intend to actually reuse and not generate a token for.

@kaby76 Thanks for your reply! Do you mean to encapsulate a rule using fragment and then write same rules (by reusing the fragmented) in different modes?

Fragments (https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md) are used when you want to use the same regular expression in more than one rule and you don't want a token for it. But you need to back up. It's not clear how you want to tokenize your input and what you want the parser to do. Do you want f"1 + 1 = {1+1}" as one token, or a bunch of tokens that the parser then parses? You need to first specify with example strings how you want the input to be tokenized. Then, design the lexer rules around that. Bart's solution assumes it's chopped up into many tokens.

@kaby76 Bart's right. By parsing the formatted string, I'm expecting an AST rather than a single token(otherwise, a simpel rule to match the string could help).

You don't really need to create a separate mode to handle expressions inside a formatted string. You could push the default mode on the stack when encountering a { in a formatted string. That also means you'd need to push- and pop mode-stacks when encountering { and } in the default mode!
A quick demo:
DemoLexer.g4
lexer grammar DemoLexer;

ADD : '+';
INT : [0-9]+;
ID : [a-zA-Z]+;
FS_START : 'f"' -> pushMode(FS_MODE);
OBRACE : '{' -> pushMode(DEFAULT_MODE);
CBRACE : '}' -> popMode;

mode FS_MODE;

FS_EXPR_START : '{' -> type(OBRACE), pushMode(DEFAULT_MODE);
FS_ATOM : ~["\r\n\\{}];
FS_ESCSPE : '\\' ~[\r\n];
FS_END : '"';

DemoParser.g4
parser grammar DemoParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=DemoLexer;
}

parse
 : expression* EOF
 ;

expression
 : expression '+' expression
 | fstring
 | ID
 | INT
 ;

fstring
 : FS_START fstring_atom* FS_END
 ;

fstring_atom
 : FS_ATOM
 | FS_ESCSPE
 | '{' expression '}'
 ;

If you now parse f"1 + 1 = {1+1}", you'd get the tokens:
16 tokens:
  1    FS_START                       'f"'
  2    FS_ATOM                        '1'
  3    FS_ATOM                        ' '
  4    FS_ATOM                        '+'
  5    FS_ATOM                        ' '
  6    FS_ATOM                        '1'
  7    FS_ATOM                        ' '
  8    FS_ATOM                        '='
  9    FS_ATOM                        ' '
  10   OBRACE                         '{'
  11   INT                            '1'
  12   ADD                            '+'
  13   INT                            '1'
  14   CBRACE                         '}'
  15   FS_END                         '"'
  16   EOF                            '<EOF>'

and the parse tree:
'- parse
   |- expression
   |  '- fstring
   |     |- 'f"' (FS_START)
   |     |- fstring_atom
   |     |  '- '1' (FS_ATOM)
   |     |- fstring_atom
   |     |  '- ' ' (FS_ATOM)
   |     |- fstring_atom
   |     |  '- '+' (FS_ATOM)
   |     |- fstring_atom
   |     |  '- ' ' (FS_ATOM)
   |     |- fstring_atom
   |     |  '- '1' (FS_ATOM)
   |     |- fstring_atom
   |     |  '- ' ' (FS_ATOM)
   |     |- fstring_atom
   |     |  '- '=' (FS_ATOM)
   |     |- fstring_atom
   |     |  '- ' ' (FS_ATOM)
   |     |- fstring_atom
   |     |  |- '{' (OBRACE)
   |     |  |- expression
   |     |  |  |- expression
   |     |  |  |  '- '1' (INT)
   |     |  |  |- '+' (ADD)
   |     |  |  '- expression
   |     |  |     '- '1' (INT)
   |     |  '- '}' (CBRACE)
   |     '- '"' (FS_END)
   '- '<EOF>'


Thanks for your reply! I just learn from you that DEFAULT_MODE could also be pushed/poped, it really helps! Meanwhile, the next question is that this solution requires OBRACE/DBRACE to have no special meaning in the DEFAULT_MODE(am i right?) If they are used as meaningful in the original context, is there a solution?
